# Retrieving a blob file from Postgres very poor performance using JPA/ Spring Boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Postgres as a file storage. I have found out that it took so long time to serve a file(9-10 secs for 300-400 kb) from the database even in the local environment(both the db and server are running on the same machine).

I know streaming would increase the performance instead of loading blob data into memory however I am surprised how long it takes to load even small-sized files. I do not have specified any configuration in application yml.

The question is how to speed up the process. Is there a configuration property that I am missing? Is there a way to speed it up? Otherwise, I have to change the file storage to file-system instead of a database which I really do not want to do it.

```
// here is my entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "t_file", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"uuid"})})
@Entity
public class FileEntity extends BaseEntity{
    @Version
    private Long version;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String uuid;
    @Lob
    private byte[] data;
}
```

In service class here is how I retrieve a file from the database

```
// here is how I retrieve a file from database
File file = fileRepository.findByUuid(uuid).map(fileMapper::map).orElseThrow(DataNotFoundException::new);
```

In the controller

```
@GetMapping("/file/download/{uuid}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadFile(@PathVariable("uuid") String uuid){
        File file = fileService.findByUuid(uuid);

        byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(file.getData());
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.valueOf(file.getMediaType()))
                .contentLength(decoded.length)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                        ContentDisposition.attachment().filename(StringUtils.substring(clearFileText(file.getName()), 0, 100))
                                .build().toString())
                .headers(headers)
                .body(decoded);
    }
```

//application yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST:localhost}:${DB_PORT:5432}/db_name
    username: postgres
    password: DB_PASS
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
```

Comment: 2 things in your code are slow, 1 you are writing to file, 2 base64 encoding that will get progressivly slower as your file size grows.  Why are you doing 2 anyway as that isn't needed generally and you should ideally directly stream to avoid tmp files and slowness.

Comment: The file naming might be confusing but it is not the java.io.File it is a POJO

Comment: You are still reading the whole byte[] which is slow, then you copy it again by base64 encoding it (which will get progressivly slower). Not to mention the memory you are occupying with this.

Comment: Are you sure the 9-10 seconds are spent in the fileService.findByUuid method? If not, you need to profile your code to see exactly what parts are taking the majority of your time - I wouldn't assume it is the DB fetch until then. Once you know, you can then look at your application code and settings, or maybe at the DB table setup (or the REST request serialization to your caller)